# Define global component in InertiaJS with Vue 3

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

I'm trying to build an application on `Laravel 8.38 - InertiaJS 0.8.4` I'm using `Vue 3` as my frontend stack.

I've multiple layouts which I need to register globally as `Vue` Component, so that I can use it in my application anywhere. I'm unable to do so, my code:

```
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { App as InertiaApp, plugin as InertiaPlugin } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';

const el = document.getElementById('app');

const app = createApp({
    render: () =>
        h(InertiaApp, {
            initialPage: JSON.parse(el.dataset.page),
            resolveComponent: (name) => require(`./../Pages/${name}`).default,
        }),
})
    .mixin({ methods: { route } })
    .use(InertiaPlugin);

app.component('app-market', () => import('./../layouts/AppMarketLayout')); //trying to import layout

app.mount(el);
```

And inside the page I'm trying to call this layout component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <app-market-layout></app-market-layout>
    </div>
</template>
```

Unable to fetch, no errors in console.

Comment: You've registered an `app-market` component, but your markup uses `app-market-layout`.

Answer (score 2):

**In Inertia JS, importing components globally is the same as using a normal Vue configuration.**

In your app.js file, you need to import the component(either inline or at the top of the file), then add the component before mounting the vue instance. [You can either do this as a mixin, or as a component.](https://chriswray.dev/posts/how-to-add-components-globally-in-an-inertiajs-application)

**So, in your case, the configuration should look like the below:**

```js
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { App as InertiaApp, plugin as InertiaPlugin } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';

//Import the component:
import AppMarket from "./../layouts/AppMarketLayout"; 

const el = document.getElementById('app');

const app = createApp({
    render: () =>
        h(InertiaApp, {
            initialPage: JSON.parse(el.dataset.page),
            resolveComponent: (name) => require(`./../Pages/${name}`).default,
        }),
})
    .mixin({ methods: { route } })
    .mixin({ components: { AppMarket } }) // << Then tell the inertia 
             // instance to use the component. 
             // You can also add this to the other mixin declaration
    .use(InertiaPlugin)
    .mount(el);
```

**Then, in your template, you can use the component like this:**

```html
<template>
    <app-market>
    </app-market>
</template>
```

**I noticed in your original post you are trying to use the component as app-market-layout. You must import the component with that name if you plan to do that.**

The configuration would look like this in app.js:

```js
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { App as InertiaApp, plugin as InertiaPlugin } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';

//Import the component: Notice the component name change.
import AppMarketLayout from "./../layouts/AppMarketLayout"; 

const el = document.getElementById('app');

const app = createApp({
    render: () =>
        h(InertiaApp, {
            initialPage: JSON.parse(el.dataset.page),
            resolveComponent: (name) => require(`./../Pages/${name}`).default,
        }),
})
    .mixin({ methods: { route } })
    .mixin({ components: { AppMarketLayout } }) // << Here the component name has Layout
    .use(InertiaPlugin)
   
    .mount(el);
```

Then in your template:

```html
<template>
    <app-market-layout>
    </app-market-layout>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having 2 layouts for backend(admin-panel) and frontend(website), achieved as follows. Using inertia default middleware file.

project/app/Http/Middleware/HandleInertiaRequests.php

```
class HandleInertiaRequests extends Middleware
{
    protected $rootView = 'app';

    public function rootView(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->segment(1) == 'admin') {
            return 'admin';
        }

        return parent::rootView($request);
    }

    public function version(Request $request)
    {
        return parent::version($request);
    }

    public function share(Request $request)
    {
        return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
            //
        ]);
    }
}
```

project/resources/js/Shared/Frontend/Layouts/Layout.vue

```
<template>

    <Header />

    <slot />

    <Footer />

</template>

<script>
    import Header from '../Partials/Header'
    import Footer from '../Partials/Footer'
    export default {
        components: {
            Header,
            Footer
        },

        name: "FrontendLayout"
    }
</script>
```

project/resources/js/Pages/Frontend/Auth/Login.vue

```
<template>
    ...
</template>

<script>
    import Layout from '@/js/Shared/Frontend/Layouts/Layout';
    export default {
        
        layout: Layout,

        metaInfo: { title: 'Login' },

        data() {
            return {
                form: this.$inertia.form({
                    'email': '',
                    'password': '',
                    'remember': false
                })
            }
        },

        methods: {
            submit() {
                this.form.post(route('login.store'))
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```